# Do children have ‘guardian’ angels, according to Matthew 18:10?

Tags: matthew, angels

In Matthew 18:10 it reads:

> "See that you do not disdain one of these little ones. For I tell you that **their angels** in heaven always see the face of my Father in heaven.
>   (Matthew 18:10, NET, emphasis mine)

> Ὁρᾶτε μὴ καταφρονήσητε ἑνὸς τῶν μικρῶν τούτων· λέγω γὰρ ὑμῖν ὅτι οἱ **ἄγγελοι αὐτῶν** ἐν οὐρανοῖς διὰ παντὸς βλέπουσιν τὸ πρόσωπον τοῦ πατρός μου τοῦ ἐν οὐρανοῖς.
>   (Matthew 18:10, NA28, emphasis mine)

Do the children have their ‘*guardian*’ angels? How should I interpret this verse?

Comment: Added another question, to help inform answers to this one: [Literary Explanations of the “Angels of Children and People”?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/28649/literary-explanations-of-the-angels-of-children-and-people).  Also closely related: [Who/what is Peter's angel?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/2418/who-what-is-peters-angel?rq=1)

Answer (score 10):

Yes, Jesus is saying that children have "guardian angels". But not just children, also adults who humble themselves as "little ones".

Jesus' message here is that it's better for a man to drown himself or be drowned by someone else in the sea, than it is for a man to offend anyone who believes in him.

> Matthew 18:6 (KJV) 6 But whoso shall offend one of these little ones which believe in me, it were better for him that a millstone were hanged about his neck, and [that] he were drowned in the depth of the sea.

Additionally, the belief in "guardian angels" was present in the disciples day.

> Acts 12:15 (KJV)
>   And they said unto her, Thou art mad. But she constantly affirmed that it was even so. Then said they, It is his angel.

Answer (score 2):

At first glance,

- Acts 12:15

> They said to her, “You are out of your mind!” But she kept insisting
> that it was so. They said, “It is **his angel**.”

This might imply that the concept of a guardian angel was common. More on this matter can be read in [this answer from Frank Luke](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/2628/27054). It seems to me that it is clear that the first Christians were convinced that everyone, like Simon Peter, has a personal Guardian Angel.

- Revelations 3:7

> And **to the angel of the church** in Philadelphia write:

This passage from Revelations may imply that there's one specific angel per church; it can also be that angels are a figure of style to mean the pastors of the churches. Then, in Revelation 1:20; 2:1, 8, 12, 18; 3:1, 7 and 14, I don't think the Bible talks of pastors but of heavenly spirits. So the heavenly spirits spoken in regards to churches seems to mean that religious and political (nations) communities also have their Guardian Angels. Also, there are specific angels also for different elements - fire (Revelation 14:18) and water (Revelation 16:5).

Personally the passage that can best indicate is the one you're referencing - Matthew 18:10. However, not even in this passage is clear if we only have one per person, if each person has one, or if only the children have it (Read also Daniel 10:21 and Daniel 12:1).

To answer the question, yes, there's Guardian Angels and not only for people but also for churches and elements. Still, do not forget that, like Jesus, if we need more we can ask the Father - Matthew 26:53. However, we can rest because better and more powerful than an angel is our beloved Jesus Christ (Hebrews 13:5-6)

- Psalm 91:10-11

> «10 No evil will happen to you, Nor will any plague come near your
> tent. 11 For He will give His angels orders concerning you, To protect
> you in all your ways.»

Answer (score 0):

**GUARDIAN ANGELS?**

**The Bible does not teach that children have “guardian angels.”**

Reading in context the passages Matthew 18:1-14 and Mark 9:33-46 we discern that Jesus, on both occasions was alone with his disciples, no children were present.  Jesus said to them:

**The bald inserts in brackets in the verses are mine.**

The Parable of the Lost Sheep.

Matthew 18:10-13 (NRSV)

> 10 “Take care that you **[apostles]** do not despise **[by what you
>   say or do]** one of these little ones; **[Jesus disciples]** for, I
>   tell you, in heaven their angels continually see the face of my Father
>   in heaven.”

Following that, to show the preciousness of the little ones, Jesus, told them the parable of the lost sheep.

> 12 “ What do you think? If a shepherd has a hundred sheep, and one of
>   them has gone astray, does he not leave the ninety-nine on the
>   mountains and go in search of the one that went astray? 13 And if he
>   finds it, truly I tell you, he rejoices over it more than over the
>   ninety-nine that never went astray.”

Mark also mentions the “little ones”. Mark 9:42(NRSV)

Temptations to Sin.

> 42 “If any of you **[apostles]** put a stumbling block  **[by what you
>   say or do]** before one of these little ones **[ Jesus disciples]**
>   who believe in me,[a] it would be better for you if a great millstone
>   were hung around your neck and you were thrown into the sea.”

To stress the seriousness of the sin, a millstone an ass usually turned, hanged around a person’s neck and thrown into the sea, with this heavy weight  a person would have no chance of surviving.

**CONCLUSION.**

We have seen that the phrase “little ones” does not refer to children but to  “Jesus disciples” the ones that believe in him. **Therefore, Jesus did not mean that children or individuals have a guardian angel, but that angels show interest in his disciples.**
Jesus also called his disciples “little flock”. Luke 12:32;  “Do not be afraid, little flock, for it is your Father’s good pleasure to give you the kingdom.

Comment: O. Nicolas is mistaken. He called a child and placed him in the midst of them in Matt 18:2

Comment: Kerrie.In verse 18:1 we read that, Jesus apostles were concerned and asked him, “Who is the greatest in the kingdom of heaven?” and he answered, “Truly I tell you, unless you change and become like children, you will never enter the kingdom of heaven.”(verse 18:3) Jesus used a living illustration- a young child-to counsel his apostles to be humble like a child, in this wise way, he tried to reason with them not to argue. The Kingdom of the heavens is different to the kingdoms of the earth where people seek glory. (NRSV)