# Where did the witch of Endor bring Samuel from?

Tags: 1-samuel

Related (but not identical): [In 1 Samuel 28:15 did the witch at Endor actually bring up the spirit of Samuel from the land of the dead?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/35252/in-1-samuel-2815-did-the-witch-at-endor-actually-bring-up-the-spirit-of-samuel)

In 1 Samuel 28, Saul consults a medium.

What view of the afterlife is reflected in these verses? Why does Samuel talk about being "brought up"? Where is he being brought up from?

Verse 15:

> Samuel said to Saul, “Why have you disturbed me by bringing me up?”

Verse 19a:

> The Lord will deliver both Israel and you into the hands of the Philistines, and tomorrow you and your sons will be with me.

**Note:** This text appears to reflect a view of the afterlife regardless of whether it was "really" Samuel or not. I'm interested in what view of the afterlife this particular text reflects, not how it fits into systematic theology as a whole.

Comment: The real question is, 'Did the witch of En-dor bring anyone from anywhere ?'. See Related, possibly Duplicate [Did the witch at Endor actually bring up the spirit of Samuel ?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/35252/in-1-samuel-2815-did-the-witch-at-endor-actually-bring-up-the-spirit-of-samuel)

Comment: The header question asks a different question to the 'Note'. I am not clear as to what you are actually trying to find out. The narrative follows proceedings from Saul's point of view. (Whatever happened, the narrative describes what Saul took from the proceedings.) [In my view.]