# Where was Samuel?

Tags: afterlife, samuel

1 Samuel 28:19 says (my paraphrase) tomorrow you and your sons will die and "be with me". Samuel had been summoned from after death. Samuel was godly.  I expected that he would have been awaiting Jesus and that Saul would have been destined for some place other than where Samuel was. Where was Samuel after he died and before Jesus rose?

Comment: Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for your question.  Please remember to take the tour (link below left) to better understand how this site works.

Comment: An obvious answer is that it wasn't really Samuel. Rather it was either a deliberate deception on the part of the witch, or one of Satan's demons, pretending to be Samuel. 
 See: [In 1 Samuel 28:15 did the witch at Endor actually bring up the spirit of Samuel from the land of the dead? - Biblical Hermeneutics Stack Exchange](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/35252/in-1-samuel-2815-did-the-witch-at-endor-actually-bring-up-the-spirit-of-samuel/35271#35271).

Answer (score 0):

1 Sam. 28:19b quotes the spirit of Samuel as saying:

> By tomorrow you and your sons will be with me, and the LORD will have
> delivered the army of Israel into the hands of the Philistines.

It is not entirely clear whether "with me" means simply "dead" or "with me in the same spiritual status." Also we should be aware that not all of Saul's sons died in the battle of Gilboa, survive and one, Ishbosheth, succeeded his father as king. (2 Samuel 2:10)

In any case, even the most righteous people in those days were considered to be dwelling in Sheol, which was not a particularly pleasant place. According to James Tabor in ["What the Bible says about Death, Afterlife, and the Future,"](https://www.newworldencyclopedia.org/entry/Sheol)

> The ancient Hebrews had no idea of an immortal soul living a full and
> vital life beyond death, nor of any resurrection or return from death.
> Human beings, like the beasts of the field, are made of "dust of the
> earth," and at death they return to that dust (Gen. 2:7; 3:19). The
> Hebrew word nephesh, traditionally translated "living soul" but more
> properly understood as "living creature," is the same word used for
> all breathing creatures and refers to nothing immortal...All the dead
> go down to Sheol, and there they lie in sleep together–whether good or
> evil, rich or poor, slave or free (Job 3:11-19). It is described as a
> region "dark and deep," "the Pit," and "the land of forgetfulness..."

Although some biblical references and later Jewish literature present a more hopeful vision of the afterlife, the above represents the general OT attitude toward Sheol.

Regarding Samuel's godliness vs. Saul's sin, we should consider that Saul's son Jonathan, was a righteous man and loyal friend of King David. Moreover, although Saul himself lost the kingship because of his sins, he had many good qualities and accomplished important victories in God's providence previously. Indeed, he and Jonathan gave their lives in battle against God's enemies and were highly praised by David in their heroic deaths.

> How the mighty are fallen... Saul and Jonathan were beloved and pleasant in their lives
> and were not separated in their death.
> They were swifter than eagles, stronger than lions. 24 O daughters of Israel, weep over Saul,
> the one who clothed you with crimson,
> the one who adorned your clothing with golden ornaments. 25 How the mighty have fallen in the midst of the battle;
> Jonathan lies slain on your high places. (2 Sam. 1)

But in any case, all souls were believed to dwell in Sheol, regardless of the degree of their righteousness.

**Thus, presuming that it is truly the spirit of Samuel speaking here, the statement that Saul and his sons would be "with him" indicates that they will soon die and join Samuel in Sheol, although not necessarily in conscious relationship with him.**